# react dynamically removing space

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, dynamic, material-ui

i have some chip(matarial-ui) i want to when i delete one of them dynamically remove space between removed chip and older chips.how can i do that?

```
                        <div className="row contactsContainer">
                            {contacts.map((contact) => (
                                <div className="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 my-5">
                                    <Chip
                                    id={contact!.phone}
                                    label="delete"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    color="primary"
                                    deleteIcon={
                                        <HighlightOffOutlinedIcon id={`del-${contact!.phone}`} />
                                    }
                                    onDelete={handeldelete}
                                    avatar={
                                        <Avatar
                                            alt={`${contact ? contact.phone : ""}`}
                                            src={lady}
                                            className={`li-avatar ${contact ? "" : "d-none"}`}
                                            title={contact?.phone}
                                        />
                                    }
                                    />
                                </div>
                            ))}
                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 my-5 ">
                            {/* <Chip
                                    id="addContact"
                                    label="delete"
                                    avatar={
                                        <Avatar
                                            alt="add contact"
                                            src={add_image}
                                            className={`li-avatar`}
                                            title="افزودن مخاطب جدید"
                                        />
                                    }
                                    /> */}
                                    <div>
                                <a onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                                    <img src={add_image} alt="add_image" className="circel_image" />
                                </a> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

any suggestion please ?
can i do it with material ui ? in this sample i use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. Can you share the code of the function you used to remove the Chip?
I believe it should remove the space when the item is deleted. Maybe you can explain your problem better?

Here is a example in material-ui for removing chips from a array of chips.

[Remove chips example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-raman-ysbhs?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: `   const handeldelete = (props: any) => {
        console.log(props.target.id);        
        console.log(props.target.id.slice(4));  
        const element = document.getElementById(props.target.id.slice(4))! as HTMLDivElement;
        element.remove(); 
    }`

Comment: You can use vanilla JS but it is recommended to useRef instead to directly manupulate by id. In your particular case i would recommend to check out the sandbox i have posted.

Comment: PS it does remove space because while you are removing the inner div with id you are not removing outer div with "md-3" class. which would still take up space of 3 sections. If you do want to follow through with your process i recommend add id part to outermost div in loop

Comment: thanks friend i solved my problem by updating state and reload it after delete and its work